# A Problem about friends and strangers using Ramsey's Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Question:

Consider a group of 8 people, each pair of which are either friends or enemies. Show
that if some person in the group has at least 6 friends, then there are 4 people who
are mutual friends or 3 people who are mutual enemies.

My approach (totally wrong and I have no idea why..):

> We know that there is one person who has at least 6 friends; that is to say, we can consider this problem in 2 cases.
>
> When this person has 7 friends:
>
> In this case, we can just temporarily ignore this person since he is a friend with everyone. Considering a complete graph of 7 persons, R(k, l) = 7. By checking the table we know that k, l = 2 and 7, which means in the group without this person, there are 2 mutual or 7 mutual enemies, or 7 mutual friends or 2 mutual enemies. Now put this person back in: there are 3 mutual or 7 mutual enemies, or 8 mutual friends or 2 mutual enemies since the previously ignored person is friend with everyone.
>
> When this person has 6 friends:
> .........

I have realized that my approach was wrong after the first case above. However, I still think it kind of makes sense.

Helps with details are appreciated!

Comment: Hint: What is $R(3,3)$?  Now consider just this person's friends.

Comment: R(3,3) = 6, which is the number of that guy's friends. However, there are 8 persons in total. How can we safely ignore that other guy?

Comment: @AngusLeo that there are 8 persons in total doesn't matter. The problem could be set for 100 people, and we still have the same conclusion. You can safely ignore all the other people.

Answer (score 1):

Take complete graph $K_8$ on $8$ vertices, whose edges are colored **red**, if two vertices $\{i,j\}$ are friends, and **blue**, if $\{i,j\}$ are enemies. Looking at one person $v$ in particular, who has $6$ friends within the group.

These 6 people he is friends with now make up a complete graph $K_6$ on $6$ vertices. As suggested in the comments, this graph is known to have either a red $K_3$ or a blue $K_3$, since $R(3,3)=6$. Therefore there is either a blue triangle, in which case we'd be done, or there is a red triangle. In the event that there is a red triangle, it joins with the vertex that wasn't friends with our original $v$. Therefore we are done.