# Seating arrangement with no two enemies adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> There are 50 people at a party. Each person is (mutually) enemies with
>   exactly 24 people. Show that if they all sit at a circular table, a
>   seating is possible such that no 2 people who are enemies sit next to
>   each other.

I am really not so sure how to approach this problem. I know that we should consider the graph with $50$ nodes. Then draw an edge between people if there are enemies.  I think we need to somehow color the edges in some clever way but I cannot get it.

There is a similar problem here: [A Problem about friends and strangers using Ramsey's Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314133/a-problem-about-friends-and-strangers-using-ramseys-theory)

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Put an edge between the people which are not enemies. Then your task is finding a Hamilton circle in this graph. Each node has degree of 25, which is equal to $\frac{n}2$. According to [Chvátal's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChvatalsTheorem.html), a Hamilton cycle exists in this graph.

Comment: they each has degree of 25.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected that.

Comment: [Dirac's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiracsTheorem.html) is the classic result I'd expect to see used here, though there have been many generalizations of it since (including Chvátal's theorem) which will also work.